# cakephp mapResource to action

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have setup cakephp to accept json but when I add the

```
Router::mapResources('members');
```

it breaks my search plugin. Can I just target a particular action in the controller members instead of all the actions.

cakephp 2.1

Controller: members

action: api

Answer (score 0):

Seems like that's not possible, but you can use it like this (in MembersController.php):

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $action = reset(explode(".", $this->request->params['action']));
    if($action == 'api') {
        $this->viewClass = 'Json'; // or whatever you want
        $this->setAction($action);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am upgrading to version 2.4, I assume I replace the Json with JsonP as 2.4 now supports it. It does not say in the documentation. Thanks for the help